# Cannot install Composer: missing json extension although installed php5-json

Tags: json, composer-php

I run this command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php#!/usr/bin/env php
```

It has error:

```
The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json
```

I checked phpinfo(), it has json already. But when I run:

```
php -m
```

I didn't see json module on it. 
How can I fix problem?

Comment: The CLI version might be another than used by phpinfo(). Check `php -i | grep json` if json support is enabled. If not install or recompile php without `--disable-json`.

Comment: json support => enable already but it has that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path to php.ini

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php5 -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```